# Does increasing the number of interferometers increase signal in FT-IR?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

I'm trying to understand why most modern FT-IRs have three interferometers. Does this improve the signal in someway or does it have another effect?

Comment: Where did you see this? There is only one interferometer in standard FTIR used in chemical labs.

Comment: Modern interferometers generally have 3. This is standard in modern instruments

Comment: Could you provide a reference which says three interferometers are employed in modern ones? I have seen opened modern FTIRs all one can see is a single interferometer.

Comment: This was information in a lecture that I am trying to understand. He did not provide a reference, just stated the fact.

Comment: My guess is it somehow improves resolution?

Comment: It is not a fact. Most likely there is some misunderstanding. Perhaps if someone is making an astronomical measurement they may employ interferometry. Routine instruments which you will encounter in a university have only one interferometer.

Comment: Would increasing the number of interferometers improve resolution?

Comment: In interferometry, the resolution is improved by the distance travelled by the mirror. It is a fundamental property of Fourier transforms.

Comment: would it increase the signal in some way? Basically we were told that modern instruments have three and we should think about why

Comment: Ask your teacher to give a reference. Have you checked your textbook? I am under the assumption you are taking an instrumental analysis course in a chemistry program not astronomy. Each interferometer is extremely expensive, the cost is prohibitive for 3 such system for regular analytical chemistry work.

Comment: It is a materials course

Comment: Still, check your reference text and see what was the context of the lecture. He must have shown a diagram. Only very fancy custom designed FT-IR systems can employ three or more. I just saw one paper in Nature in 2020. Certainly, this is not common or commercial to begin with. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41378-019-0111-0.

Comment: yes thats the same paper i saw

Comment: Most FT-IR instruments have one interferometer, as @M.Farooq says. The resolution is inversely proportional to twice the distance (in cm) that the moving mirror moves. But, for a small integrated chip, only an inadequately small mirror movement distance is feasible. So the authors of the 2020 linked paper had the nice idea of using N interferometers, driven by the *same* actuator, so that the desired travel distance could be divied up into N coherently scanned *contiguous* shorter distances. Then they process the N interferograms as necessary in order to achieve their goal spectral resolution.

Comment: Do have have handouts for the course? A direct quote from the offending slide would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I use FTIR in Physics, pretty much top-of the-range commercial instruments (actually more than just IR - ours go down to the UV and would do THz if we had the detectors; this isn't uncommon so I'll mainly refer to FT rather than FTIR).  There's definitely only one interferometer in each of our systems (and the ones used by our friends in Chemistry).  In astronomy FT spectroscopy has been used on the ground, but the best IR work these days is done from space using dispersive instruments (e.g. [Spitzer's IRS](http://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/images/2939-Spitzer-s-Cool-Components-Instruments)).

The only common commercial use of three series-connected spectral devices (trying to coin a deliberately vague term) is dispersive instruments, which use three diffraction gratings for high resolution spectra and, for Raman spectroscopy, laser rejection with low stray light. A good benchtop FT instrument (with one interferometer) can give just as good resolution, though slowly and without the dynamic range. I mention this because if you were giving a lecture introducing a range of systems and techniques, and skipped a slide or two, you could jump from FTIR to triple dispersive systems and cause a lot of confusion.